# In VSCode, when I try to use the shortcut to copy a line, Ubuntu is triggering a shortcut to move to a different workspace?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm working in Visual Studio Code and I attempt to use the shortcut to Copy Line Down (`Alt + Shift + Ctrl + Down Arrow`) it seems like Ubuntu is taking over and triggering a shortcut to switch to a different workspace.

I've checked my keyboard shortcuts for Ubuntu and it seems like the only shortcuts that would doing that are mapped to `Shift + Super + PageDown`.  I don't see anything in the keyboard shortcuts that is mapped to the same shortcut (`Alt + Shift + Ctrl + Down Arrow`).  Am I missing something here?  Any suggestions on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a whole line you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> without highlight anything (just stay in the line).
If you want to move a line you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to move the line up and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> move the line down.

Answer (score 0):

New Ubuntu user. Spent few hours sweating on this. Seems Ubuntu is blocking <kbd>ALT</kbd> key press as it is reserved for OS purposes (disturbing development?!).

Best new shortcut I could come up with that does not interfere with other major VSCode functionality corresponding to **Copy Line Up/Down** commands are below. From `keybindings.json`

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+.",
    "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+,",
    "command": "-editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

To copy a line up or down in VS code;

```
alt + shift + UP (or DOWN key).
```

Here are some more shortcuts which may help you in other conditions;

```
Alt + up or down (moves the whole line up or down.)
ctrl + right or left key (jumps from word to word towards right or left.)
ctrl + shift + right or left key(jumps from word to word and also selects in the same direction.)
```